# How to merge all intersecting tuples in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples, and would like to merge together any tuples that intersect. Mathematically speaking, each tuple is a set, but is not typed as such in the higher-level code.

My current solution involves comparing every tuple to every other tuple, and merging until no overlap exists. Is there a more efficient or Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Current solution (works as intended):

```py
    def overlap(tup_list): #pass a list of tuples
        """
        For a list of tuples, merge together any tuples that intersect at at least one element.
        Returns a reduced set of tuples.
        """
        set_list = [tuple(sorted(set(x))) for x in tup_list] #first-order cleanup: reduce duplication within elements by making each element a set. Sorted for consistent order of tuple elements. Then converted back to tuple so hashable.
        superset = set(set_list) #second-order clean up: reduce duplication of tuples by making governing list a set
        reduced = False #init "reduced" bool
        while reduced == False: #run until fully reduced
            op = False #init/reset "operations performed" bool
            for i in superset.copy():
                for j in superset.copy():
                    if set(i) == set(j): #if same set, skip
                        continue
                    elif set(i).isdisjoint(set(j)): #if sets don't overlap, skip
                        continue
                    else: #sets do overlap, append union; remove individuals
                        new_member = tuple(set(i).union(set(j))) #union tuple
                        if new_member not in superset:
                            superset.add(new_member)
                            op = True
                        if i in superset and i != new_member:
                            superset.remove(i)
                            op = True
                        if j in superset and j != new_member:
                            superset.remove(j)
                            op = True
            if op == False:
                reduced = True #if no operations performed, consider to be fully reduced
        return(superset)
```

Examples:

```py
input: [(1,2,3),(4,5),(6,7,1)]
returns: {(4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6, 7)}
```

```py
input: [(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(3,4),(10,)]
returns: {(10,), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)}
```

(as expected)

Comment: Code improvement questions are on topic for Stack Overflow, but you may get better feedback on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @skrrgwasme Thanks, if crossposting is allowed, I'll ask it there too. If not, I'll just leave it here.

Comment: [Avoiding crossposting would be appreciated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Sets are unordered; you are casting sets to tuples prior to comparing them... Should you sort them before comparing? Maybe your problem can be solved with connected components algorithms like union find? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I am casting back to sets before calling any methods, so I'm not sure that sorting would do anything - or am I misunderstanding you? I don't like casting back and forth as I have, but was having hashability issues when trying to do: `set_list = [set(x) for x in tup_list]; superset = set(tuplist)`

Comment: `new_member = tuple(set(i).union(set(j)))` the order of new member is not known. `new_member not in superset:` compares a potentially randomly ordered tuple to other potentially randomly ordered tuples... The same goes with `if i in superset and i != new_member:`

Comment: On my machine, with python 3.7, the following input gives two different outputs: `print(overlap([(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(4,6,5),(10,11),]))` and `print(overlap([(1,3,2),(1,2,3),(4,6,5),(10,11),]))` gives respectively: `{(10, 11), (4, 6, 5), (1, 2, 3)}` and `{(10, 11), (1, 3, 2), (4, 6, 5), (1, 2, 3)}` where the two outputs should be the same.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Good point on the ordering! I will look into that.

Comment: I've added sorting order to the elements being compared: `set_list = [tuple(sorted(set(x))) for x in tup_list]`. Also note that there was a typo in the originally posted code: `superset = set(tup_list)` is now `superset = set(set_list)` as it should be.